# Clean heavily rusted structural steel

Tags: rust-removal, preparation

I'm hoping to use some scrap structural steel pipes and plates to build a large BBQ/Smoker, but they're all pretty heavily rusted. I've seen people in tutorials use both wire wheels and preparation discs to do this, but none have explained their choice.

They all seem similarly priced and all have the same description of their function! Ideally I'd like to select the one which least marks the underlying steel.

I'm currently choosing between just about everything in this category:
http://www.screwfix.com/c/tools/cleaning-preparation/cat5990034

Comment: For rust removal I find flap wheels more effective than wire wheels - but I'm not a statistically significant sample. I'd be tempted to try electrolysis using a battery charger, washing soda solution and a sacrificial steel anode.

Comment: Wouldn't the anode need to be of similar mass to the amount of rust I'm removing? and if so, how would I work that kind of thing out - I don't want to start on it (by commandeering the bathtub) and then realise I need weeks and an enormous anode!

Comment: You're [tempted](https://www.youtube.com/user/mrpete222/search?query=rust) though aren't you!

Comment: I am tempted, but I get the sense you might be trying to kill me ;)

Comment: He's not trying to kill you. But, just in case, would you mind updating your will so your executor will post the results of your attempt here?

Comment: I'll make sure to do that! And will be experimenting outside!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above?

It's structural steel, you can just leave it rusty (if it happens to be corten, the rust actually keeps it from rusting further...) This may lack **W**ife **A**pproval **F**actor for your backyard BBQ, however.

Least marking (and least direct effort, dust, noise) **electrolytic rust removal** - submerge it in a tub of water, outside, with sodium carbonate (washing soda) mixed in. Connect a low-voltage DC supply to the thing you want the rust off of, and a sacraficial electrode. Polarity is **-** to the thing you are derusting, **+** to the thing you are sacrificing. Both should be in the tub, but they should not touch. Turn on the power, let it bubble (that's hydrogen, which is why you do this OUTSIDE, only, not inside.)

For mechanical rust removal when looking for effectiveness/speed rather than "least marking" I use a knotted wire brush in an angle grinder. Conditioning disks will probably mark a bit less and definitely work slower, IME.

Comment: Ha - look what @RedGrittyBrick commented while I was writing that. Keep it outside, not in the bathtub... The sacrificial anode mass (lost) would only  be similar to the mass of RUST, not the mass of STEEL. If you can find something like a block of graphite to use as a sacrifice, it makes a bit less of a mess. Keep the connection to it above the waterline.

Comment: OK, so electrolytic removal is ruled out then unless I buy a paddling pool or another bathtub. I've seen The Martian, so knowing it's hydrogen rules out indoors!

Comment: Plastic storage containers, old plastic drums (my local "used drum vendor" has clean ones that were used for food products for $20) or dig a hole in the ground and line it with a plastic sheet...

Comment: How long would the electrolysis process take? I'm just trying to work out if I need to find somewhere out of the rain for hours or days...

Comment: Keep the power supply out of the rain, run wire (low voltage, recall) and don't worry about the rain otherwise. Time is variable on a LOT of factors - how much rust, the concentration of the solution, the amount of current you can supply from the power supply (I use an old, dumb 12V automobile battery charger.) Folks restoring cannon from sunken ships will take months at it, most things in my personal experience take hours or days, but those are tool-sized things, mostly. Citric acid and no electricity is another approach (just don't forget about it - unlike electrolysis, it can be overdone)

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll probably give it a go at least on some similar waste material

Comment: Now I want to go find something rusty just for an excuse to try this.

Comment: I admit I was skeptical as all heck the first time (see comment on naval jelly below - I was kinda used to being let down by "rust removal" methods.) My test victim was a pair of needlenose pliers I'd found by the side of the road (New England, the roads get salted in winter.) They were solidly frozen. The rust was removed; the pliers work again, though the joint is now loose, since the rusting and removal of the rust in the joint left it somewhat looser fitting than when it was made. Hardened items should be baked after to avoid issues with hydrogen embrittlement, or a different method used.

Comment: So I was prepping a bucket to test this in, when I had a bit of a revelation which might be useful to other users. We have huge plastic bins outside for our rubbish (trash) here in the UK - everyone does! I'm going to clean one of these and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rust removal product called Naval Jelly.  It is a gel product usually applied with a brush.  It dissolves the rust and leaves a clean paintable surface when used according to the instructions.  Then there is the option of media blasting which is probably the most common method for rust removal of large jobs.  I'm not offering these as "the best" solution, but it will accomplish your task without the introduction of electricity.

Comment: I have always found this product *very* disappointing; I'd like to believe it does what it claims, but I have never found it to be true in practice.

Comment: Huh.  I've used it with success on several projects. Of course, it's not going to remove anything other than the iron oxide. I typically use it on projects that have tight spots making any forms of mechanical removal difficult.

Comment: It just occurred to me the real reason I used the Jelly.  It easily portable to remote locations (ie. The middle of the woods).